# Difference between speaker and subwoofer voice coil

Tags: audio, coil, speakers, sound

What is the difference between speaker, woofer, and subwoofer voice coils?

Comment: None. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: Than why subwoofer produce low frequency and speaker don't

Comment: it is not the coil where the difference is

Comment: You mean we can use speaker voice coil in well designed subwoofer Right

Comment: Is **voice coil** your fourth item or is that your guess answer ?

Comment: There is no other difference than size. Obviously the coil size must be suitable for the size of the cone and speaker element, because it's the size if the element which defines what frequencies it can produce.

Comment: As @Justme says, it's all about size. ;) A subwoofer will have larger [excursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excursion_(audio)) and a larger diameter magnet and a larger cone diameter and a larger mounting depth and will move a larger amount of air per cycle. A tweeter will be at the opposite extreme for all of those. The voice coil diameter will follow the magnet diameter and its length will follow the designed excursion.

Comment: The subwoofer has also a "lowest" resonance frequency (size of cone). Some parameters? https://mynewmicrophone.com/full-list-thiele-small-speaker-parameters-w-descriptions/#Lces:-Electrical-Inductance-Including-Air-Load

Comment: Read this also https://hometheateracademy.com/lower-hz-means-more-bass/